# How do I get how many days straight user login in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, authentication

How do I get how many days user straight login in one month or years?

Here is an example:

```
user_id   | login
1         | 2017-05-01
2         | 2017-05-01
1         | 2017-05-03
1         | 2017-05-04
1         | 2017-05-05
```

I want get many days for user_id 1 is 3 days straight login with a MySQL query.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you got a code that you have been working on? Please post it here. Take a tour of SO, read the help section to find out how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `SELECT` all the rows in descending order of `login`, store previous date and user id into temp variables and compare the date difference for each row, e.g.:

```
SELECT user_id, login, 
IF(@previousid = user_id AND DATEDIFF(@previouslogin, login) = 1, @count:= @Count + 1, @count:=1) as `count`,
@previousid := user_id, @previouslogin := login
FROM logins, (SELECT @previousid := null, @count := 1, @previouslogin := null) a
ORDER BY login desc;
```

Once done, you can wrap this query into another `SELECT` use `GROUP BY` with `MAX` aggregate function to get the max number of days for each user, e.g.:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(count) as `count`
FROM (
 SELECT user_id, login, 
 IF(@previousid = user_id AND DATEDIFF(@previouslogin, login) = 1, @count:= @Count + 1, @count:=1) as `count`,
 @previousid := user_id, @previouslogin := login
 FROM logins, (SELECT @previousid := null, @count := 1, @previouslogin := null) a
 ORDER BY login desc) a
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14f7e9/14/0)**.